# angular Controller array error

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am using the angular `ng-repeat` function, in my controller i am trying to create an array however i keep getting an error message in my inspector.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token [
```

below is a snippet of my code..

```
var app = angular.module("homeApp", []);
 app.controller("entriesView", function ($scope){
$scope.itemEntry = {[
    {

    image: "https://cms.myspacecdn.com/cms/x/13/47/112013-priscilla-600.jpg"
    },
    image1: "https://cms.myspacecdn.com/cms/x/13/47/112013-priscilla-600.jpg"


];
  }

});
```

can someone let me know where i am going wrong, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recreate `itemEntry` like:

```
$scope.itemEntry = [            
    {image: "https://cms.myspacecdn.com/cms/x/13/47/112013-priscilla-600.jpg"},
    {image1: "https://cms.myspacecdn.com/cms/x/13/47/112013-priscilla-600.jpg"}    
];
```

The `itemEntry` represents list of objects but not Object of list

Answer (score 1):

Array uses `[]` braces. You wrapped your array in `{}` which is for objects. Objects need key/value pairs, so since your object only contains the array is throwing a syntax error

Remove outer `{}`

Comment: yeah, you are right. deleted my answer. I did not want to be rude or anything, just think that you really need have some solid foundations in JS before learning AngularJS.

Comment: @arturgrzesiak agree that more than basic knowledge of objects/arrays is needed...especially to understand scope...just better to be diplomatic. No need to delete answer